# In PySide6, show() method for QSystemIconTrayIcon() not working after calling hide() function

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside2, pyside6, qsystemtrayicon

My app needs to dynamically show or hide system tray. But once I call `.hide()` function on it, and then call `.show()` on it, It does not show up. Same behavior with `.setVisible(...)`.

#### Minimal Reproducible Code

I've created a minimal reproducible code to show what issue is happening with `QSystemTrayIcon` class of **PySide6**.

```py
import os
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
import resources_rc

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Image
def _image(name: str):
    return os.path.join(':', 'saved_files', 'images', f'{name}.png')

# Setup system tray
tray = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon(_image('folder')))
tray.show()
print('> Running\n')

def toggle_tray():
    tray.setVisible(not tray.isVisible())
    # tray.setIcon(QIcon(_image('folder')))                             # WORKAROUND (read below)
    print(f'[State Toggled] Tray Visible = {tray.isVisible()}')

# Timer to show/hide the tray icon
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(toggle_tray)
timer.start(3000)
    
app.exec()
```

#### How it should work:

It should show system tray icon and then after 3 seconds, hide. Then after 3 seconds, show. Then after 3 seconds, hide. And cycle continues.

#### How it's behaving:

It shows up perfectly on start *(as it should)*, and then after 3 seconds it hides *(as it should)*, but ***after next 3 seconds, IT DOESN'T SHOW UP*** *(as it should have)*.

#### Workaround I found *(after many trials and errors)*:

- **Workaround:** Set the icon for system tray *again* using `tray.setIcon(QIcon(_image('folder')))` after hiding the tray icon using `.hide()` or `.setVisible(False)`.
- **Result:** Everything works as intended, but that's *just a workaround*.
- **Question:** I don't understand why the original code is not working? Is it because `.hide()` or `.setVisible(False)` is removing the icon from `QSystemTrayIcon()` or is it something else? Maybe It's a Bug? I really need your help regarding this.

#### Info:

- **Platform:** *Windows 11 Pro v22621.2361* *(stable build)*
- **Python version:** *Python 3.11.4*
- **PySide version:** *PySide6==6.5.3* **|** *PySide6-Addons==6.5.3* **|** *PySide6-Essentials==6.5.3*

Comment: Blocking functions should ***never*** be used in an event-loop based toolkit. Use QTimer if you want to delay a function or call it at regular intervals. Your while loop is completely blocking proper event handling.

Comment: I used a while loop only for the sake of reproducing the problem without much inputs from user, and it's not being used in my app. In anycase, even without while loop its not working. I can provide different reproducible code without the while loop if you want.

Comment: @musicamante I **added** another minimal reproducible code **without while loop** to original post.

Comment: Sorry but that update is still not consistent, as multiple subsequent calls may have unexpected results. As said, a *reliable* code (even one that *actually* shows the issue) should always allow the proper time to the event loop to process everything. QSystemTrayIcon uses system APIs, and multiple hide/show calls may have unexpected results if called within the same execution "cycle". Please provide a valid [mre] using QTimer or any *properly delayed* user/system event.

Comment: @musicamante **Added** another code which uses `QTimer` to show the behavior in original post *(Edit 2)*. And result is still same.

Comment: Please reduce your post by including only the valid example (the last one): the first one is irrelevant because it blocks the event loop (Qt also needs to process system events and a while loop prevents that), and the second is ambiguous for similar reasons. Also add details about your environment (OS, PySide/Qt versions, possible VM, etc.) as this may be a bug and we need a more precise context to understand it; for instance, I cannot reproduce it on Linux with Qt5/6 (PySide and PyQt, but I doubt that it would matter).

Comment: @musicamante Edited the original post as pointed out by you. Now it looks clean and with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a bug in Qt. I reported and they fixed it in v6.5.4, v6.6.1, v6.7.0.